# What does C-u 0 mean in Emacs

Tags: emacs

What does C-u 0 followed by another command mean in general in Emacs?

For example,

I thought C-k and C-u 0 C-k were the same, but find out that

C-u 0 C-k kill the part of the current line before the cursor, while C-k kill the the part after.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**

It provides number `0` to the next command.

**Long answer**

`C-u` in emacs called `universal-argument`. It's begin a numeric argument for the following command. Digits or minus sign following `C-u` make up the numeric argument. You can read more details about `C-u` by typing `C-h k C-u` or read online documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html).

Understanding meaning of `C-u`, now you can know that, `C-u 0 C-k` and `C-k` are not the same. The first, `C-k` is called with an numeric argument, it's number zero. The second `C-k` is called alone. It leads to different behavior.

From [Killing by Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html#Killing-by-Lines) section of emacs manual:

> The simplest kill command is C-k (kill-line). If used at the end of a
>   line, it kills the line-ending newline character, merging the next
>   line into the current one (thus, a blank line is entirely removed).
>   Otherwise, **C-k kills all the text from point up to the end of the
>   line;** if point was originally at the beginning of the line, this
>   leaves the line blank.
>
> ...
>
> When C-k is given a positive argument n, it kills n lines and the
>   newlines that follow them (text on the current line before point is
>   not killed). With a negative argument −n, it kills n lines preceding
>   the current line, together with the text on the current line before
>   point. **C-k with an argument of zero kills the text before point on the
>   current line.**

Comment: Thanks. (1) By default, is there a more convenient way than C-u 0 C-k? (2) similarly is there a more convenient way than backspace (which do you think requires too much finger movement?)?

Comment: (1)`M-0 C-k` (2) I'm often map `C-h` for backspace, and remap help key for another like`C-c h`.

Comment: (1) Is `C-u <number>` same as `M-<number>`?

Comment: @Tim:not the same entirely. But if you want send numeric argument to a command, example 0, you can use `M-0`, `C-0`, `C-M-0` or `C-u 0`.

Comment: how the universal is different from M-# ?